# How to filter by a list of integers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm in charge of payroll and they want me to give an extra bonus to our employees which **ID numbers are storaged in a list.**

The 'ID' column only contains integers. I know if I use str.contains I get an error, but what can I do? **I need something similar to str.contains** but with **int**

```
bonus = [ 1513 , 5454 , 6545 , 3425 , 32424, 2341 ,3424 ,4568, 4812]
employees = (df['ID'].str.contains(bonus)) & ((df['SALARY'] < 5000))

#I get this error (Which makes sense):
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

I want an out put something like:

```
ID     SALARY
1513   2933
3424   2500
3425   1542
2341   3600
```

This is just a sample the list **WAY larger**

Comment: `df['ID'].isin(bonus)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the `str.contains` function is intended to be used to check if a string value contains a given substring. What you want to use is `isin`:

```
(df['ID'].isin(bonus))
```

Combining this together with your other requirement, we need to query on a given column, so we'll a call to `loc`:

```
employees = df.isin({'ID': bonus}).loc[df['SALARY'] < 5000]
```

Comment: Or... `df.query('ID in @bonus and SALARY < 5000')`

Comment: @JonClements That's an interesting result. Is there a performance benefit or is it just a difference in syntax?

Comment: Mostly just syntax and it tends to chain more nicely when doing a lot of ops in one go

Comment: (and sometimes it's just immediately more readable as to what it's doing)

Comment: Thank you so much guys, it´s really good to know there are experienced people like you who help the newbies like me.

Comment: @JorgeVilla Glad we could help

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to get the result in dataframe.

```
df.loc[df["ID"].isin(bonus)].loc[df["SALARY"] < 5000]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isin` and `&` to join the condition

```py
out = df[df['ID'].isin(bonus) & (df['SALARY'] < 5000)]
```